# What ring does qemu execute in?

Tags: linux, qemu, xen, kvm, lxc

What ring does qemu execute in when not tied into an existing hypervisor?

Any more complete documentation on this subject would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QEMU always runs in the user ring, even when tied into a hypervisor.

Answer (score 1):

Qemu runs in ring level 3 (User-space) while the hypervisor "KVM" that it uses for hardware-assisted mode runs in run-level level 0 (Kernel-space).